# View Truncated Tables from All Databases on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, truncate

I'm working on a project that focuses on truncated tables in a server. The goal of the project is to record all truncated tables in the audit table. I've worked on a code below that works fine on a single database; however, I'm not able to run that code automatically on all databases. I've tried writing:

1. Cursor
2. Using `Exec ('Use ' + @DatabaseName + ';')` in the stored procedure.
3. Exec sp_MSforeachDB and the stored procedure.

Every single time I try to run the sproc for all databases it is executed on a database where the code exists. How can I execute it on all databases.

Main query:

```
DBCC TRACEON (2537) -- All Log Files

;WITH  TranCte as ( SELECT
        [Transaction Id]
        ,[Transaction Name]
        ,[Begin Time]
        ,SUSER_SNAME( [Transaction SID]) AS [User]
        ,[Operation] FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL) WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'TRUNCATE TABLE'),

ObjectCte AS
                      (SELECT
                            [Lock Information]
                            ,[Transaction Name]
                            ,[Transaction Id]
                      FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
                      WHERE [Transaction Id] IN (SELECT
                                                                                   [Transaction Id]
                                                                      FROM       fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
                                                                      WHERE       [Transaction Name] = 'TRUNCATE TABLE' )
                                   AND [Lock Information] LIKE '%SCH_M OBJECT%'),

ConvertStringToRows ( [Lock Information], starts, pos, [Transaction ID]) AS
                      (SELECT
                            [Lock Information]
                            ,1
                            ,CHARINDEX( ':', [Lock Information])
                            ,[Transaction ID]
                      FROM ObjectCte UNION ALL SELECT
                            [Lock Information]
                            ,pos + 1
                            ,CHARINDEX( ':', [Lock Information], pos + 1)
                            ,[Transaction ID]
                      FROM ConvertStringToRows
                      WHERE pos > 0 ),

ConvertStringToRowsDetails AS (SELECT
        *
        ,RowN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Lock Information] , [Transaction ID] ORDER BY Starts , [Transaction ID] )
        ,ColumnType =
                                   CASE ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Lock Information], [Transaction ID] ORDER BY Starts , [Transaction ID] )
                                          WHEN 3 THEN 'Database'
                                          WHEN 4 THEN 'Object'
                                   END
        ,DetailsID = SUBSTRING ([Lock Information], starts, CASE
               WHEN pos > 0 THEN pos - starts
               ELSE LEN ([Lock Information])
        END)

FROM ConvertStringToRows )

, CTE_Report
                      AS (SELECT
                            e.*
                            ,ObjectID = ob .DetailsID
                            ,DatabaseID = db .DetailsID
                            ,o. [Lock Information]
                            ,TableName = OBJECT_NAME (ob. DetailsID, db.DetailsID )
                            ,[Database] = DB_NAME (db. DetailsID)
                      FROM TranCte e
                      JOIN ObjectCte o
                            ON e .[Transaction Id] = o .[Transaction Id]
                      JOIN ConvertStringToRowsDetails db
                            ON o .[Lock Information] = db .[Lock Information]
                            AND db .ColumnType = 'Database'
                      JOIN ConvertStringToRowsDetails ob
                            ON o .[Lock Information] = ob .[Lock Information]
                            AND ob .ColumnType = 'Object' )


SELECT        * FROM CTE_Report
```

Comment: Another option is to add it to the master database give it an `sp_` prefix and mark it as a system object. Then it can dynamically run in the context of any database. same as things like `exec somedb..sp_help` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will reference the system tables for the database you're currently in every time, so will only show that database's data.

If you want to execute it across databases, you'll need to either put the code into each database and run it from there using one of the methods you've already tried, or create composite views and functions that aggregate the code from a specified list of databases, and read from them.

Or you *could* put all that code into dynamic SQL and EXEC it against a specified database inside your sproc. But I really wouldn't do that.

**EDIT** - Commenter is right. Ignore my earlier prejudice. Do the dynamic SQL thing. One of the very few SO questions where it's the right answer.

Comment: Why "I really wouldn't do that"? Seems preferable to having to do either of the other options you mention to me. The only dynamic element that needs replacing is the `USE dbname`.

Comment: The methods I mentioned did not do the trick. I believe the reason is that "GO" command cannot be executed.

Comment: @MartinSmith OK, you've got me, my 'someone on SO has asked a question that implies solving by dynamic SQL' alert probably tripped a bit early. Will edit, in hindsight you're right. Do the above in dynamic SQL.

Comment: @BIDude It's not GO that's the problem, it's that you're referencing the system tables for the specific database you're looking at. Do the dynamic SQL thing to point it at the right database and EXEC the code, and it'll be hunky dory.